# CakePHP/AJAX - Sending data to database on a stop draggable event

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, cakephp

Creating a CakePHP application where objects are being dragged on a "layout area" and once they stop dragging the element I want AJAX to send the current position (xpos, ypos) to the database. Some reason I keep getting the failed response.

Currently my JQUERY & AJAX look like such....

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> //Draggable + AJAX Submit Position
       $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.square, .round').draggable({
start: function() {

},
drag: function() {

},
stop: function() {
var position = $(this).position();
var y = position.top;
var x = position.left;
//alert(position.top + " " + position.left);
var formData = {xpos:x,ypos:y}; //Array

$.ajax({
    url : "<?php echo $posturl;?>",
    type: "POST",
    data : formData,
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      alert("SUCCESS!");
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      alert("FAIL!");
    }
});


}
});
       });

</script>
```

And my controller/action (I'm using edit to post changes to item in db) in CakePHP being called into $posturl....

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Table->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid table'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->Table->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The table has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The table could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Table.' . $this->Table->primaryKey => $id));
            $this->request->data = $this->Table->find('first', $options);
        }
        $stores = $this->Table->Store->find('list');
        $floorplans = $this->Table->Floorplan->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('stores', 'floorplans'));
    }
```

Using this in my view to create the URL using HTML helper in Cake...

```
$posturl = $this->Html->url(array('action'=>'edit','controller'=>'Tables'));
```

My view is actually inside of a different controller, but I'm calling out to the Tables controller function.

Comment: Are you getting the fail alert, right??

Comment: Yes I am. I'm thinking I must be calling something wrong or missing something under controller I'm calling perhaps, since my AJAX is fine I'm sure.

Comment: Just bellow the formData initialization add this line: `console.log(formData);` and post the output